# How can I fix this program?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been working on this program with these instructions:

Station Information Write a program that gives information about underground stations. The
user should first input how many stations they wish to ask about and then be allowed to name that
many stations. The program should say whether they have step free access and the distance that
must be travelled to get from entrance to platform. A new type called Station must be created (a
record type) and each separate piece of information about a station should be stored in a separate
field of the record (its name - a String, whether they have step-free access - a boolean, and the
distance in metres - an integer).

A separate method must be written that given a String (a station name) as argument returns a String
containing the correct information about the station. The String should be printed by the calling
method. An example run of the program: Your answer need only
include the information about known stations as in this example.

```
How many stations do you need to know about? 4

What station do you need to know about? Stepney Green
Stepney Green does not have step free access.
It is 100m from entrance to platform.

What station do you need to know about? Kings Cross
Kings Cross does have step free access.
It is 700m from entrance to platform.

What station do you need to know about? Oxford Street
Oxford Street is not a London Underground Station.

What station do you need to know about? Oxford Circus
Oxford Circus does have step free access.
It is 200m from entrance to platform.
```

The program doesn't have any errors but doesn't show me the results I need.

This is what I get using the same example:

```
how many stations do you want to know about?
4
what station do you want to know about?
Stepney Green
Stepney Green does not have step free access. it is 100m away from the entrance to platform.
what station do you want to know about?
Kings Cross
Kings Cross does have step free access. it is 700m away from the entrance to platform.
what station do you want to know about?
Oxford Street
Oxford Street is not a London underground station
what station do you want to know about?
Oxford Circus
Oxford Circus does have step free access. it is 200m away from the entrance to platform.
```

Comment: The way you modified your question eliminates all the problems and your question doesn't seem to make sense anymore. What are you asking now? In general, you shouldn't change your question unless you made a mistake when typing it or to answer to requests for clarification.

Comment: The result I get is still different from what I am supposed to get. For the first line for example, The result is supposed to show the 4 in the same line as the question but it just passes to the next line. How do I get it on the same line. The rest of the result also has the same problem more or less.

Comment: Please point out how it is different. Is it just the newlines and "it" instead of "It"?

Comment: It doesn't follow the linearity of the result.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check if I understood correctly what you were asking. Still, you should revert the "wrong" parts of your question, otherwise future readers won't understand the first part of my answer and your question may be downvoted because the "new" question is something that's usually very well covered in any decent tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

"Stepney Green" and "stepney green" are not the same string. Case matters. You need to use the [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) method from the `String` class, as in, for example

```
if (station.equalsIgnoreCase("stepney green")) {
    System.out.println(stepneyGreenMessage);
}
```

About the missing newline in the output message you can just add a literal `\n` where you need it to go to a new line. But I would rewrite `create_message` (which should really be called `createMessage` to respect java naming conventions) like this to avoid repetitions:

```
public static String create_message(Station station) {
    String message = station.name + " does ";
    if (!station.step_free_access) { // try to avoid " == true" in if conditions
        message += "not ";
    }
    message += "have step free access.\n"; // notice the "\n" to go to a newline
    message +=  "It is " + station.distance_from_platform + "m away from the entrance to platform.";
    return message;
}
```

There are other optimizations that could be added (like using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` but I think they go beyond the exercise you're trying to solve.